calculating total current consumption before and after voltage regulator
I have a simple circuit.
IC1 is a standard 7805 voltage regulator.
Let's assume the battery G1 is 10 volts and all LED's each have 1V for its voltage drop.
Do I calculate total current consumption as follows?
Current=9/R1+9/R2+4/R3+4/R4?
I picked numbers 9 and 4 because 10 is the source voltage and I subtracted 1 for the LED voltage drop. I picked 4 because voltage regulator feeds 5V max and I subtract 1 for the LED voltage drop.
Is this the proper way to calculate the grand total current consumption of this circuit?


Yes, that is the correct way to add the currents, with the slight addition of the 7805's quiescent current which is 5-8 mA. In practice, LED voltage drops will vary somewhat from their datasheet value as well.
